# Super over for super over

Tags: rules, cricket, icc, tie-breaker

If the runs scored in a super over by two teams were level, how will the winning side be determined?

E.g. Team A scored 10 runs in 6 balls and Team B scored 10 runs in 5/6 balls with two wickets lost; what will they do?

Will they go for another super over? If so, how many times will they keep going for another super over while they all result in ties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Super over`, or `one over eliminator` is used when both the teams end up on the same score at the end of a T20 game. This is similar to a penalty shootout in football or a tie-breaker in tennis.

Both team captains have to give a list of three batsmen and a bowler from their team to the umpire. These 4 players from each team will participate in the super over. The chasing team at the end of the T20 game will bat first in the super-over.

```
In case of a tie at the end of a super over, will they go for another super over?
```

**No**, another super over will not be played. Instead the winner will be

- the team that has scored the most boundaries in the match (main match + super over).
- If the above is still a tie, the team that has scored the most boundaries in the match (main match only).
- If still equal, a count-back from the final ball of the one over eliminator shall be 
  conducted. The team with the higher scoring delivery shall be the winner. If a team 
  loses two wickets during its over, then any unbowled deliveries will be counted as 
  dot balls. Note that for this purpose, the runs scored from a delivery is defined as 
  the total team runs scored since the completion of the previous legitimate ball, i.e 
  including any runs resulting from wides, no ball or penalty runs.

> Example: Assuming that the game has ended in a tie and goes to a super over. Both teams end up on 15 runs in the super over. If the number of boundaries in the game and the super over for both teams are the same, then the third tie-break is applied.

```
+------------------+--------+--------+    
| RUNS SCORED FROM | TEAM 1 | TEAM 2 |    
+------------------+--------+--------+    
|     Ball 6       |   1    |   1    |    
|     Ball 5       |   2    |   2    |    
|     Ball 4       |   6    |   4    |    
|     Ball 3       |   4    |   6    |    
|     Ball 2       |   1    |   W    |    
|     Ball 1       |   1    |   2    |    
+------------------+--------+--------+
```

> In this example both teams scored an equal number of runs from the 6th and 
>   5th ball of their innings. However team 1 scored 6 runs from its 4th ball while 
>   team 2 scored only 4 runs, so **team 1 is the winner**.

*Source*:  [Appendix 7.14](http://static.icc-cricket.com/ugc/documents/DOC_988F9785FD768E4902737F0ACA2E856B_1352699332977_153.pdf) in ICC's T20I Playing Condition Handbook.

The first time a tie-breaker at the end of the super over was applied was when [Australia defeated England](http://www.stabroeknews.com/2010/sports/05/06/aussies-take-bizarre-win-over-title-holders/) in the Women’s World Twenty20 game by the virtue of having hit more sixes than England during the game.

Answer (score 5):

This is the rule if the runs scored by two teams in Super Over is equal...

> In the event of the teams having the same score after super over has
>   been completed, the team that hit the most number of sixes combined
>   from its two innings in both the main match and the super over shall
>   be the winner.
>
> If the number sixes hit by both teams is equal, the team whose batsmen
>   score the most number fours in its two innings (main innings + super
>   over) will be the match winner.

[Reference 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Over#Rules) [Reference 2](http://www.itsonlycricket.com/entry/1111/)

Comment: what happen if the fours hit by the two teams were equal?...... ok, I give up:-)