# Super Over tie rule

Tags: rules, cricket, tie-breaker

It is mentioned in [this post](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2500/super-over-for-super-over) that if the boundaries count in the main match is equal then a count-back from the final ball of the one over eliminator would be 
conducted.

Consider if still it looks equal as below, How the winning team will be decided?

```
+------------------+--------+--------+    
| RUNS SCORED FROM | TEAM 1 | TEAM 2 |    
+------------------+--------+--------+    
|     Ball 6       |   1    |   1    |    
|     Ball 5       |   2    |   2    |    
|     Ball 4       |   6    |   6    |    
|     Ball 3       |   4    |   4    |    
|     Ball 2       |   1    |   1    |    
|     Ball 1       |   1    |   1    |    
+------------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Edited your question for not closing as a dupe of [this question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2500/super-over-for-super-over). You can rollback the edit, if not interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each tournament will have its own playing conditions.

I'm not sure about other tournaments, as per the [playing conditions of IPL](http://www.iplt20.com/about/2014/match-playing-conditions/54/appendix-7)

> The super over will be declared as a tie.

Then, if the match is a league match.

> 1 point will be given per team
>
> If both the teams have an equal number of points their relative
>   positions shall be determined by the following:
>
> a: the team with the most wins in matches in the League during the
>   season will be placed in the higher position
>
> b: if there are teams with equal points and equal wins during the
>   season, then in such case the team with the higher net run rate will
>   be placed in the higher position
>
> c: if following the net run rate calculation above there are teams
>   which are still equal, then the team with the higher number of wickets
>   taken per balls bowled in the matches played that season in which
>   results were achieved will be placed in the higher position
>
> d: if still equal at the end of the regular season then the team
>   position will be determined by **drawing lots**.

If the match is a play off match (Final, the Eliminator, Qualifier 1 or Qualifier 2 matches).

> The team which, at the end of the relevant regular Season, finished in
>   the higher position in the League table will be deemed the winner of
>   the relevant play-off match.

[Law 21 - IPL Playing conditions.](http://www.iplt20.com/about/2014/match-playing-conditions/26/law-21-the-result)

Comment: This is it. Everyone need to note that such rules (e.g. deciding winner or qualifying team) are up to the tournament. Such rules can be (and are) changed every tournament.